# Is it better to have polyfills as import statements with babel-preset-env or add them in entries at webpack.config.js?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, babel-polyfill

`babel-preset-env` offers the option [`useBuiltIns`](https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env#usebuiltins) to apply it to `babel-polyfill` and transform `import 'babel-polyfill'` to specific, environment-based, `import 'core-js/whatever`.

Is this transformation applied if I add `babel-polyfill` in my Webpack entry section (see example below), or in that case `useBuiltIns` is ignored and replaced by all possible imports?

```
entry: {
  app: ['babel-polyfill', './src/app.js']
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It works when you are specifing:

```
"presets": [ ..., "env" ]
```

It doesn't related to the entry point as your `./src/app.js` already includes some code with *requirements*, I guess. I just don't understand what do you want to achieve by adding `babel-polyfill` to the entry point, but seems it no effect in this case.

I'll try to elaborate how it works. There is a `babel-preset-env` plugin which prepares the list of transformation plugins and polyfills. This list is used by `transform-polyfill-require-plugin` which look for `import` and `require` statements and replaces it by list of environment-specific modules.

It doesn't related to the entry point at all. By adding the `babel-polyfill` you just add it's code into your bundle. So the `transform-polyfill-require-plugin` doesn't work there anyhow. It's possible to check it via a simple debugging.

And you don't need it really. You can just add `require("babel-polyfill");` once in your app as it's noticed in the docs. You even can't import `babel-polyfill` twice as it might cause an error as it writes down itself into the `global` and has a check for the collision.

Comment: My question is, specifically, if `useBuiltIns` is applied if instead of imports I add `babel-polyfill` to my entry point in Webpack: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/

Comment: Try to understand the answer before voting down. You may ask if it's not clear. I've expanded the answer to explain more precisely.

Comment: I voted down because *This answer is not useful* (as per Stack Overflow guidelines).

The problem with your original answer is that you’re explaining why you don’t need to have `babel-polyfill` in the entry point if you have either `require("babel-polyfill");` or `import "babel-polyfill";`. The incorrect assumption that I probably wasn’t explicit about is that my *`./src/app.js` already includes some code with requirements*.

Thank you for clarifying in your third paragraph. So the answer is that they’re different and probably using `babel-polyfill` in the entry point is worse.

Comment: I concluded it is worse because it makes the bundle bigger. However, from a software engineering point of view, I think it’s cleaner to have polyfills in Webpack instead of in your app code.

Maybe there’s no *best* option, as each one has its pros and cons.